# Null textbox then Redirect

Tags: php

So i have a form method post in index.php where in it will send the data from a textbox to another page which is print.php.

now what i want to do is if the textbox from index.php is null it wont redirect to print.php or if it redirect to print.php it will be redirected back to index.php.
index.php format

```
<form action="print.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="faidf" id="faidf" size="25" value="" maxlength="25"/></td>
<input type ="submit" value="Print">
```

print.php

```
<?php
$faidf = $_POST['faidf'];
if(isset($_POST['faidf'])) {
    echo "<td><font size=2>FAID:$faidf</td><td></font></td>";
}
else {
    echo "FAID is missing";
    }
    ?>
```

instead of FAID is missing could i redirect it home because i have about 10more php wherein it needs the variable of $faidf so the whole printd.php is utterly useless if the textbox is blank.thanks

Comment: Why you are not trying with javascript or jquery from client side? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: my knowledge about the subject itself is limited and trying to learn as of the moment and would love to accept suggestion in which one cave man could understand hehe.im still a student trying to learn from practicing "simple" problems like this in which im having a hard time. hehe

Comment: thank you for the link i will read it will all my heart soul and mind. its not like im not trying.i dont know which is to try thats why im asking.it makes be sad to be told that im not trying. :( im seriously trying my best and will be grateful for advice. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways:

## Way 1:

Use JQuery/JavaScript for the form validation process onsubmit of the form. It will redirect only in case where there is data found in textbox.

## Way 2:

Check the length of provided post data and if the length is less than 1 return it to the previous page.

I will advice you to use the JavaScript/JQuery as it will run on all cross browsers and easy to implementation and changed easyly

Answer (score 0):

first add onchange function to your textbox

```
<input type="text" onchange="myFunction(this)" name="faidf" id="faidf" size="25" value="" maxlength="25"/>
```

and add an Id for the button

```
<input type ="submit" value="Print" id="btn" />
```

and add script tag in your page :

```
function myFunction(e)
{
  var x=document.getElementById("btn");
  if (e.value == ''){
      x.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
     x.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

and instead of your echo at print.php add location header

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: could you please explain this one? i tired it and i have some question."myFunction(this)" or it should be "myFunction(e)". it should disable the print button if its empty right?

Comment: Mr. @Yinks, in the input tag its a function call so you'll pass the input object to the function and the `function(e)` is the function that takes e as a parameter where we sent the `this` object to it, and yes its not allowed to submit the board unless the input has value.